# Make validation tooltiptext look thinner

Tags: css

Here is how my validation tooltip text look like :

[image]

What I want to achieve is something like this :

[image]

What CSS does it need to display the text like the below image?

Note that the second image, I scrrenshot it from another website, both run a same browser, I check the CSS for both tooltips but they're have the same definitions. I don't know why mine look thicker with a little shadow inside the text.

I'm using this font-family :

```
font-family: "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック", "ＭＳ ゴシック", Osaka, sans-serif;
```

Comment: you might want to start by using a more generic / browser friendly font family. Not sure what language that is in.

Comment: @foreyez never mind I figured it out. It was the text-shadow property that causes this

Comment: @foreyez just can't understand why when using F12 to debug, I can't find anywhere revelant to this text-shadow thing ...